# How to ensure that is_search() return false after query_posts

Tags: query-posts

I know I am not supposed to use query_posts

The thing is I have a program that already do that.

```
query_posts("");
echo "is_search():" . is_search();
query_posts("s=kucing");
echo "is_search after():" . is_search();
```

Now the first echo returns empty.

The second returns 1

I wonder if there is some global variable I can set to 0 so that is_search() will return false even though I did

```
query_posts("s=kucing");
```

Answer (score 7):

Your real big problem here **is** the use of `query_posts`. It breaks the main query object, and sets the main query object to the query made by `query_posts`. What you are seeing is quite normal.

Your real solution here with the use of `query_posts` would be is to reset the main query back to what it should be. This is where `wp_reset_query()` comes in. If this is a normal page, `is_search()` will return `false` after `wp_reset_query()` as the main query is reset to the page's main query.

```
query_posts( '&s=crap' );
// Do your loop as normal
wp_reset_query(); // Add this after your loop
var_dump( is_search() ); // Will return bool ( false )
```

Remember, use of `query_posts` is highly discouraged. You should be using `WP_Query`

Comment: Great answer. I  like it better. :)

Comment: If I reset the main query back than the themes would display the regular  posts rather than those containing crap

Comment: No, it will not. Remember, `wp_reset_query()` goes after you have run your loop, after you have displayed the posts from `query_posts`. You have to reset your main query object as plugins and other custom code relies on this object. That is why `query_posts` is really really bad. You cannot just set `is_search()` to false to expect everything to be OK.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `global $wp_query` and set the `is_search` to false;

```
global $wp_query;
query_posts(""); //is_search is false now
query_posts("s=kucing"); //is_search is set to true
$wp_query->is_search = false; //is_search is set to false
```

Comment: Let me try this one first because it seems easier